# Most and least sold item in array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Im trying to output the most and least sold item in array but it either ouputs incorrectly or a blank value and i cannot see why. Each item has an array for the price, name, and number sold. My thinking was to identify which the least sold item was and then to use that to access the name array so it would out put the name of the item rather than the lowest number.

Heres what i have done so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
int iNumOfItems = 0;
string sChoice = "";
string sItems[5] = {};
int iItemPrice[5] = {};
int iNumSold[5] = {};
int iItemNum = 0;
int iMostSoldItem = iNumSold[0];
int iLeastSoldItem = iNumSold[0];
int iCount = 0;


int main()
{
    do {

        cout << "--------- ENTER NEW ITEMS ---------\n\nPlease enter the item Name: ";
        cin >> sItems[iCount];
        cout << "\nPlease enter the price of: " << sItems[iCount] << "\n";
        cin >> iItemPrice[iCount];
        cout << "\nWould you like to enter another item? Y/N \n";
        cin >> sChoice;

        if (sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y")
        {
            ++iCount;
            ++iNumOfItems;
        }

    } while ((sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y") && iNumOfItems < 5);

    //most sold item

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (iNumSold[i] > iMostSoldItem) {
            iMostSoldItem = iNumSold[i];

        }
    }
    cout << "\nMost sold item: " << sItems[iMostSoldItem];


    //least sold item
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (iNumSold[i] < iLeastSoldItem) {
            iLeastSoldItem = iNumSold[i];

        }
    }
    cout << "\nLeast sold item: " << sItems[iLeastSoldItem];

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be a whole lot easier using 1) array of `struct` instead of parallel arrays, and 2) a standard library container of `struct` instead of an array

Comment: Sounds like a chance to get to learn how to use a [debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of use - what you've posted doesn't compile; and can't be throw into a function to see the error ... as such you're asking people to do quite a lot to be able to help you

Comment: i diddnt put all of the code on this as it was too large so copied the bits that were relevent it does work just doesnt ouput the correct values

Comment: We don't want all your code. What we require is a [mcve].

Comment: appologies eddited the code

Comment: Sounds like a job for [std::minmax_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on answering the question, not on improving the code:

```
cout << "\nMost sold item: "<< sItems[iMostSoldItem];
```

`iMostSoldItem` is the value of the most items sold, not the index. To fix, you would need another variable to keep track of the index:

```
int mostSoldItemIndex;
```

Then

```
mostSoldItemIndex = 0;
iMostSoldItem = iNumSold[0]; // Move this here
for (int i = 1; i < iNumOfItems; i++) {   // Changed 5 to iNumOfItems
    if (iNumSold[i] > iMostSoldItem) {
        iMostSoldItem = iNumSold[i];
        mostSoldItemIndex = i;   // Save the index
    }
}
cout << "\nMost sold item: "<< sItems[mostSoldItemIndex];
```

You need to do this for `iLeastSoldItem` as well.

I failed to notice, you never ask the user to enter the number of each item sold. You need to add that:

```
cout << "--------- ENTER NEW ITEMS ---------\n\nPlease enter the item Name: ";
cin >> sItems[iCount];
cout << "\nPlease enter the price of: " << sItems[iCount] << "\n";
cin >> iItemPrice[iCount];
// Add this
cout << "\nPlease enter the number sold of: " << sItems[iCount] << "\n";
cin >> iNumSold[iCount];
```

Comment: tried above just outputs the first entry as most and least sold

Comment: @callumtaylorx I just noticed: you never ask the user to enter the number of items sold. You need to add that. Will update my answer.

Comment: tried above aswell getting error reading characters of string

Comment: @callumtaylorx Just tested on ideone (https://ideone.com/znWdcc) and it worked ok. Can you provide more details about the error?

Comment: appologies had missed something works perfectly can see where i went wrong thankyou for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the STL your code can be much simplified.

`std::minmax_element` can replace both loops with one function call:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Item {
  std::string name;
  int price = 0;
  int sold = 0;
};

class Main {
private:
  std::vector<Item> items;
public:
  void input_item () {
    auto &item = items.emplace_back ();
    std::cout << "--------- ENTER NEW ITEMS ---------\n";
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Please enter the item Name: ";
    std::cin >> item.name;
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "Please enter the price of: " << item.name << "\n";
    std::cin >> item.price;
    std::cout << "\n";
  }

  void input_items () {
    std::string sChoice = "y";
    while ((sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y")) {
      input_item ();
      std::cout << "Would you like to enter another item? Y/N \n";
      std::cin >> sChoice;
    }
  }

  void input_sold_item_qty () {
    std::cout << "--------- INPUT SOLD ITEMS ---------\n";
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Please select an item: \n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size (); i++) {
      std::cout << 1 + i << ": " << items.at (i).name << "\n";
    }
    int item_num;
    std::cin >> item_num;
    std::cout << "\n";
    auto &item = items.at (item_num - 1);
    std::cout << "Please enter the ammount sold: " << item.name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Quantity: ";
    std::cin >> item.sold;
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "You have sold " << item.sold << " of " << item.name << "\n";
  }

  void input_sold_item_qtys () {
    std::string sChoice = "y";
    while (sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y") {
      input_sold_item_qty ();
      std::cout << "Would you like to input more sold items? Y/N \n";
      std::cin >> sChoice;
    }
  }

  static bool sold_compare (const Item &l, const Item &r) {
    return l.sold < r.sold;
  }

  void print_least_most_sold_items () {
    auto pair = std::minmax_element (std::begin (items), std::end (items), sold_compare);
    std::cout << "Most sold item: " << pair.second->name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Least sold item: " << pair.first->name << "\n";
  }
};

int main () {
  Main m;
  m.input_items ();
  m.input_sold_item_qtys ();
  m.print_least_most_sold_items ();
}
```

Comment: Why not make `sold_compare` a lambda in the call to `std::minmax_element`?

Comment: Sure, that would work as well. I originally had two functions that reused the static comparer function. I don't think a lambda would make this much more readable though. YMMV